# Why does not my cronjob work?

Tags: macos, unix, cron

I'm studying how to set up ubuntu server.
Today, I learned how to use crontab on the web and I tried it in my local mac computer. (not ubuntu server)

```
crontab -l
* * * * * /bin/echo 'hi'
```

I added a very simple cron job to check if it runs correctly, but it does not run!!

I tried the following, but both do not work.

## A

```
crontab -e
* * * * * /bin/echo 'hi'
```

## B

```
crontab -e
* * * * * echo 'hi'
```

I'm expecting that I see 'hi' every minute on my terminal console.

What am I doing wrong?

## Updated

```
mail
```

I tried `mail` command and I saw the list of log echoing hi.
it seems it is running but how can I see 'hi' in my terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` writes on `stdout`, which is normally attached to your Terminal. `crontab` jobs however, don't have Terminals associated with them - if you have a little think about it. What would happen if you had multiple Terminals open, how would it know which one to send your "hi" to? It doesn't.

As you are learning, it might be informative to try the following, though it is not for production quality code.

Start a Terminal, and get its associated device special file:

```
tty
/dev/ttys000
```

Now make a `cronjob` that writes there:

```
crontab -e
* * * * * echo "Hi" > /dev/ttys000
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply! Thanks for your help!